# In tone (emotion) analysis in nltk, how can I have an indicator of weak/strong emotion on a scale?

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis, emotion

Having a text like "single dose" my python program returns a dictionary of probabilities of various emotions like

```
 {'joy': 0.18, 'shame': 0.03, 'sadness': 0.53, 'guilt': 0.01, 'disgust': 0.14, 'anger': 0.08, 'fear': 0.007}
```

(using NaiveBayes classifier and a set of training data)

However, as you see, this text does not have any strong emotion in it.
Therefore I need to have another dictionary that indicates how strong is each emotion.

As another instance in customer review, I want it to return a strong emotion indicator for "Fuck this" as opposed to weak emotion indicator for "meh".
But more so that I don't want to tag factual sentences Like "I bought this on Saturday"

I have not tried anything as I did not find any clue for that. The only thing that I hope, is that I convert the dictionary above to another dictionary with weakness/strength scale directly and avoid a separate training and classification process for this purpose.

Another thing is that the sum of probabilities in the dictionary above is 1 but in my desirable output, it doesn't have to be necessarily 1.(i.e. normalized)

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want different outcomes (Strong positive/weak postive/weak negative/strong negative).  it appears your model was not designed for your task.  See if you can find a different one, or train one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the code of the nltk Naive Bayes classifier:

http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html

You will see that the scores are normalized by this call:

```
return DictionaryProbDist(logprob, normalize=True, log=True)
```

If you change that line for normalize=False, you will get the raw probabilities.